# one file is escaping my exception and being created

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to retrieve some document titles and create files with them using Python 2.7.8 as follows:

```
subject_list= ['this should work1', '[0000] Unhandled exception in Unknown - class something::something', 'this should work2', 
               '[0001] URGENT: something is not working', '[0002] subject: something / all users combined into 1', 'this should work3']
description_list = ['1', '2', '3']


for i in subject_list:
    try:
        fls = open(i + ".txt", 'w')
        fls.writelines('')
        fls.close()
    except Exception as a:
        print(a)
        pass
```

I try to create a .txt file with the subject.
IF I want to make this work without having a [Error 22] invalid mode ('w') 
I have to replace all the characters which are not accepted when creating a file (|, \, /, :, ", ?, *,<, >)

When I don't remove the special characters, A files is created with no extension which shouldn't have([0001] URGENT: something is not working) , but later raises the exception for the other files accordingly.

Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: The error is printed because there is a print command in the except clause, but what do you mean by "iterates over something returning a print of the error rather than just skipping it and moving along"? It's not quite clear. Are any files written before you hit an error or does this happen on the first file?

Comment: it doesnt happen on the first file, happens on the 20th (for ex.) and then i will see  [Error 22] invalid mode ('w') for the same file like 50 times and then the program stops.  then i exclude a special character from this file (*star) and i will be able to build 50 txt files before hitting another file with another special character ('/' this time) and i see the  [Error 22] invalid mode ('w') multiple times brfore my program stops....and so on and so on, until i exclude all special characters

Comment: Perhaps you're not capturing the correct exception. Try changing "except IOError as a:" to simply "except:". It's not a best practice to use a general exception clause, but it'll give us a clue.

Comment: I did test that as well and got the same behavior.

Comment: Try isolating the problem. Copy the loop code to somewhere else, and instead of using beatbox, just iterate over a static list of names in which one or two names have special characters. See if you get the same behavior. If so, copy this list of names here so I can test. I cannot test the code with the beatbox part.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the problem with the following code:

```
file_names = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test*4', 'test5', 'test6']
for file_name in file_names:
    try:
        fls = open(file_name + '.txt', 'w')
        fls.writelines(file_name + ' content')
        fls.close()
        print 'Saved', file_name
    except IOError as a:
        print a
```

The output is:

```
Saved test1
Saved test2
Saved test3
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'test*4.txt'
Saved test5
Saved test6
```

Which shows that test*4 was skipped, but the following files were saved successfully. There must be some other problem with your code (perhaps with the beatbox part), but you can avoid it by replacing all special characters with underscores. It's completely painless with regular expressions:

```
file_name = 'hello*world!!'
file_name_clean = re.sub(r'[^\w]+', '_', file_name)
print file_name_clean
```

output:

```
hello_world_
```

Comment: if you try with a dictionary?  because i get the data from a json response and specify that i want to create a subject from the key's value, and in the key value is where i have special chars. Or i will try, haha, sry, just realised you had posted the last comment of my earlier thread

Answer (score 0):

Okay you have a lot going on here. First, why don't you try opening `item.Subject` instead of `instance[n]`, since you are iterating over (with `for item in instance`). Like this:

```
svc = beatbox.PythonClient()
svc.login(username, password+token)
instance = svc.query("my SOQL Query")
for item in instance:
    try:
        fls = open(item.Subject + '.txt', 'w')
        fls.writelines(item.Description)
        fls.close()
    except IOError as a:
        print(a)
        #pass this isn't needed
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, and yes this proves helpful in order to make my code more efficient, but the error persists, and i have no idea why